# How to see the sign of an entangled PDE

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Suppose I have functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ that I am maximising with respect to arguments $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. First order conditions for optimisation is given by

$$f_1(x_1^*,x_2,a)=1$$

$$f_2(x_1,x_2^*,a)=1$$

where superscript $^*$ indicates that values that maximize the function, and $a$ is some constant. I know that $x_1^*$ is increasing in $a$ if we keep $x_2$ fixed, since

$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial a}>0 \hspace{0.2cm} ; \hspace{0.2cm} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}<0 $$

For $i=1,2$, which implies that when $a$ increases both $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$ increase.[1] Since it may be that $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}<0$. Does an increase in $a$ (locally) increase $x_1^*$?

---

My attempt, through the implicit function theorem:

$$ \frac{\partial x_1^*}{\partial a} =- \frac{\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial x_2^*}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial a}}{\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial x_2^*}{\partial x_1}} ,$$

whose sign, I think, determines whether the effect is positive or negative.

---

[1] $f_1$ increases, which needs to be offset by an increase in $x_1$ to satisfy the FOC.

Comment: Are $f_1$ and $f_2$ two separate functions or the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively?

Comment: @Hans Yes, these are separate functions.

Comment: Before I get into answering your question, it is better to clarify the problem first. I think you have confused yourself. If the two functions are really completely unrelated, there is no point putting them together. So why do you put them together in one problem?